# This App store notes in my phone run it very first time it runs then I click the add button and app crashes. Problem in loading data in app from phone

Tags: java, android, sql

This app will do two things one, show all the notes user has stored on the device, and add notes on the device. But when I run app for the very first time assuming there is no data stored and the database in which the data is supposed to be stored is empty the app runs but when I click on the button for adding notes it crashes and then if I clear app from recents and open again it crashes mostly because there is some data in the database. And if I clear storage and then run it runs so, when I try to store any data and then run it crashes. In my code, I reload the recyclerView after entering new notes and opening app for the first time by calling the reload method in the adapter class, and most probably that method has some problem in the adapter class.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.notes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NotesAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public static NoteDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), NoteDatabase.class, "notes")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new NotesAdapter();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.add_note_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            database.noteDao().create();
            //Log.e("cs50", "Error has occured");
            adapter.reload();
            //Log.e("cs50", "Error has occured");
        }
    });


    adapter.reload();
}
}
```

Note.java

```
package com.example.notes;

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note
{
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "contents")
    public String contents;

}
```

NoteDao.java Interface

```
package com.example.notes;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface NoteDao
{
    @Query("INSERT INTO notes (contents) VALUES ('New note')")
    void create();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    List<Note> getAllNotes();

    @Query("UPDATE notes SET contents = :contents WHERE id = :id")
    void save(String contents, int id);
}
```

NoteDataBase.java

```
package com.example.notes;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase
{
    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();
}
```

NotesAdapter.java

```
    package com.example.notes;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder>
{
    public static class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        LinearLayout containerView;
        TextView textView;
        NoteViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_row);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_row_text);
        }
    }

    public List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.note_row, parent, false);

        return new NoteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Note current = notes.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(current.contents);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    public void reload()
    {
        notes = MainActivity.database.noteDao().getAllNotes();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_note_button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat = "@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="@color/cardview_light_background"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

note_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/note_row">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/note_row_text"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notes"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

[Error message in the Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSLaK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i see two problems in your code

1) You need to create an instance of your database you can't just call your DAO like that

```
public static synchronized MyDB getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), MyDB.class, DB_NAME)
               .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
               .addCallback(roomCallback)
               .build();
     }
      return instance;
}
```

2) When you manipulate Room you should use an other Thread for any interaction with the database so you need to call an Async function

An example of insert function Asynchronous -->

```
private static class InsertProductAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Product, Void, Void> {
        private ProductDao  productDao;

        private InsertProductAsyncTask(ProductDao productDao) { this.productDao = productDao; }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Product... product) {
            productDao.insertProduct(product[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```